# Why is the signum function $=2u(t) - 1$?

Tags: discrete-signals, proof

Basically I couldnt find proof for this anywhere though it's a very simple and basic equation.

Comment: what u(t)? xxxx

Comment: heaviside unit step function.  $$ u(t) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad t\ge 0 \\ 0 \quad t<0 \end{cases} $$  it would have to be defined as 1/2 for t=0 if it was tied to the sgn() function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signum function is defined by

$$\text{sgn}(t)=\begin{cases}-1,&t<0\\0,&t=0\\1,&t>0\end{cases}$$

Using the half-maximum convention, the unit step function is defined by

$$u(t)=\begin{cases}0,&t<0\\\frac12,&t=0\\1,&t>0\end{cases}$$

From these two definitions it should be obvious that

$$\text{sgn}(t)=2u(t)-1$$

must hold.

Comment: why is the step function 1/2 in 0? I've never heard about the half-maximum convention

Comment: @BehindTheSciences: That's one possible convention for defining a value at $t=0$. Often it's not necessary to bother about $t=0$, but if it is, that convention usually makes most sense. It is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Answer (score 1):

Its simple actually,

By neglecting the t = 0 in sgn(t),

sgn(t) =

\begin{cases}-1,&t<0\\1,&t>0\end{cases}

Add 1 to sgn(t),

sgn(t) + 1 =
\begin{cases}0,&t<0\\2,&t>0\end{cases}

Now we can compare sgn(t) + 1 and u(t) easily, where,

u(t)= \begin{cases}0,&t<0\\1,&t>0\end{cases}

hence, comparatively, u(t) = 1/2 [ sgn(t) + 1 ] i.e, sgn(t) = 2u(t) − 1